# Translate Stata "gen" into R

Tags: r, stata

I am reproducing some Stata code in R and struggling with the following command:

```
gen new_var=((var1_a==1 & var1_b==0) | (var2_a==1 & var2_b==0))
```

I am generally familiar with the `gen` syntax, but in this case I do not understand how values are assigned based on the boolean condition.

What would the above be in R?

Comment: Omit `gen` is the only change needed.

Comment: (In general, more people will be able to help with translation questions if you can explain what the code is meant to do, as there are many more people fluent in R than who are fluent in both stata and R.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stata, in general the above `gen` command will work because you have variables in your in-memory dataset (similar to a single R dataframe) named `var1_a`, `var1_b`, `var_2_a`, and `var2_b`.  If these exist as vectors in your R environment, then our colleague Nick Cox is exactly correct: all is needed is the statement without the leading `gen`.. (although typically in R we would write it like this):

```
new_var <- (var1_a==1 & var1_b==0) | (var2_a==1 & var2_b==0)
```

However, if you have a data frame object, say `df` that contains columns with these names, and the objective is to add another column to `df` that reflects your logical conditions (like adding a new variable ("column") to the dataset in Stata using `generate / gen`. In this case, the above approach will not work as the columns `var1_a`, `var1_b`, etc will not be found in the global environment.

Instead, to add a new column called `new_var` to the dataframe called `df`, we would write something like this:

```
df["new_var"] <- (df$var1_a==1 & df$var1_b==0) | (df$var2_a==1 & var2_b==0)
```

Comment: The analogy is deeper, as Stata now has frames too, and that could be the context for a command.